# How to v-bind in multiple object array in vue3 with typescript?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, typeerror, tiptap

I was made texteditor in vue3 + vite + ts, with [tiptap](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/tree/main/demos/src/Examples/CollaborativeEditing/Vue), but in `item.type` , `item.icon` ... all item attributes say `'error'`.

That say `ToolbarItem | Divider` not have each other attributes:

`item.type => Property 'type' does not exist on type 'ToolbarItem | Divider', Property 'type' does not exist on type 'ToolbarItem'`,

My code in parents component:

```html
<template v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
    <div v-if="item.type === 'divider'" class="divider" :key="`divider${index}`" />
    <Child v-else :key="index"
            :icon="item.icon" :title="item.title"
            :action="item.action" :isActive="item.isActive"/>
</template>
```

```js
interface ToolbarItem {
    icon: string,
    title: string,
    action: Function,
    isActive?: Function
}

interface Divider {
    type: string
}

const items: Array<ToolbarItem | Divider> = [
    {
        icon: 'bold',
        title: 'Bold',
        action: () => props.editor.commands.toggleBold(),
        isActive: () => props.editor.isActive('bold'),
    },
    {
        type: 'divider'
    },
    ...
]
```

My code in Child component:

```js
interface ToolbarButtonProps {
    icon: string,
    title: string,
    action: Function,
    isActive?: Function
}

const props = defineProps<ToolbarButtonProps>()
```

I hope to separatly inject items to div or Child and stop see error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> that say ToolbarItem | Divider not have each other attributes

Like the error suggests, your array of objects do not have similar properties. JavaScript allows you to access properties that do not exist in an object. For ex:

```js
const fruit = { shape: 'round', color: 'red' };
console.log(fruit.size); // undefined
```

Now, while JavaScript allows this, we shouldn't just use it. It becomes harder to read the code since you'd expect that `fruit.size` returns the value of `size`, but it results to `undefined` instead. This is why TypeScript is complaining.

There are a couple of ways to address the TypeScript issue, however, perhaps we can try re-thinking how we create our template.

```js
<template v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
    <div v-if="item.type === 'divider'" class="divider" :key="`divider${index}`" />
    <Child v-else :key="index"
            :icon="item.icon" :title="item.title"
            :action="item.action" :isActive="item.isActive"/>
</template>
```

Looking at this code, it seems the purpose of the `div` element is to add some sort of divider or margin between each rendered `Child` component. Try reworking it this way:

```js
<template>
  <section v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
    <Child
      :key="index"
      :action="item.action"
      :icon="item.icon"
      :isActive="item.isActive"
      :title="item.title"
    />
    <div
      v-if="index < items.length"
      :key="`divider${index}`"
      class="divider"
    />
  </section>
</template>
```

With this, you don't need a *"divider"* in `items` and you don't need to conditionally render `Child`:

```
const items: Array<ToolbarItem> = [
  {
    icon: 'bold',
    title: 'Bold',
    action: () => props.editor.commands.toggleBold(),
    isActive: () => props.editor.isActive('bold'),
  },
  ...
]
```

Here is an [example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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).

Comment: "divider"  is margin between nth Child component! but your answer is claerly help to me!
'we can try re-thinking' yes really!
I really thanks to your answer